# WPF Change Path Data in storyboard

Tags: wpf, storyboard

So I have a path setup like this

```
<Grid x:Name="arrowPanel">
    <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="M0,4 H8 M4,4 V8Z" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" Height="8" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Stretch="None" Width="8">
        <!--Not sure what to do here -->
    </Path>
</Grid>
```

I have a storyboard setup like this

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpandStateGroup">
    <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
        <Storyboard>
            <!-- Something to change the data to this 'M0,5 H10'(A minus sign)-->
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed">
        <Storyboard>
            <!-- Something to change the data back to it's original 'M0,5 H10 M5,5 V10Z' (A plus sign)-->
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

I do not know how to alter the data aspect of the path to make these transformations.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to transform the actual geometry data. No way to do this comes to mind right away. But maybe it is a option to show both paths and animate the opacity to make a fade transition from one to the other. That may not be exactly what you want, but it may also look nice.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` to "animate" the `Data` property of the Path:

```
<Storyboard>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0"
        Storyboard.TargetName="arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Data">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <Geometry>M0,5 H10</Geometry>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to get the results I was looking for I created two paths that occupied the same area. One with the plus sign and the other with the minus sign (The plus sign without the vertical path).
**Object:**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="plusSignPanel">
        <!-- Minus -->
        <Path Data="M0,4 H8" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2" Height="8" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Stretch="None" Width="8"/>
        <!-- Plus -->
        <Path x:Name="plusSign" Data="M0,4 H8 M4,4 V8Z" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" Height="8" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Stretch="None" Width="8"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And then all I did was change the color from black to transparent using the coloranimation on the plus sign for expanded state and vice versa with the collapsed state:

**Animation:**

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="ExpandStateGroup">
    <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
        <Storyboard>
            <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" Storyboard.TargetName="plusSign" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Transparent"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed">
        <Storyboard>
            <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" Storyboard.TargetName="plusSign" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Stroke).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Black"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```